# In iOS, can you open a file in another application without calling the "Open In" Menu?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidocumentinteraction, uidocument

Using UIDocumentInteractionController, I can open an "Open In" menu for a File URL.  If there is only one application that can handle (viewer/editor) that type of file, three options are presented:

1. The Viewer Application
2. Mail
3. Copy

Is there a way I can send the file immediately to the "Viewer" application without opening the "Open In" menu?

PLEASE NOTE:  The file type is a CUSTOM file type that only the 1 viewer application can handle.

Comment: I suspect that viewer application has some support for this, for example you can use its own URL scheme which may or may not support opening a specific file; I mean something like `viewerapp:///path/to/ownfile.ext`.

Comment: How would the view app gain access to that file?  Is there some common place to put the file on the OS?  That is:  What is the PATH in the URL pointing to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS, is there a temporary directory that all applications can see?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720069/ios-is-there-a-temporary-directory-that-all-applications-can-see)

Comment: The Question is NOT a duplicate of my other question.  The comment above caused the other question to be created, but THIS QUESTION is very different in nature:  This is asking how to bypass the "Open In" menu.  The other question is about temporary directories.  Please read the questions more carefully before flagging it as a duplicate.